# dataflow error with sdk_container_image apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.40.0

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I spent a while trying to deploy a custom container to Google Cloud Dataflow (in python).  Eventually I scoped my bug down to this minimal example:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
--output gs://<your-ouput-dir> \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--project=<your-project-id> \
--region us-central1 \
--temp_location=gs://<your-tmp-location> \
--worker_harness_container_image=apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.40.0 \
--experiment=use_runner_v2
```

Many variants of this job failed, always with the error log

```
Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 285, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_code' on <module 'dill._dill' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py'>
```

Ultimately I found a solution: downgrading the sdk_container_image.  Specifically this job completed successfully

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
--output gs://<your-ouput-dir> \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--project=<your-project-id> \
--region us-central1 \
--temp_location=gs://<your-tmp-location> \
--worker_harness_container_image=apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.38.0 \
--experiment=use_runner_v2
```

From here I was able to build a custom worker harness (by pip installing `apache-beam[gcp]==2.38.0`, and copying the scripts in `/opt/apache/beam` from the `apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.38.0` docker image).  Simply downgrading was a bit unsatisfying.  Has anyone encountered this StockUnpickler bug, and found a way around it on apache-beam 2.40.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a common issue in this case, are you sure the runner of your Dataflow job (virtual env) has the same versions of Apache Beam Python, used by the Docker image (2.40.0) ?

The runner instantiates the Dataflow job and the Docker image is used by workers.

To work well the versions used by the runner should be the same as the versions used in the Docker image.

It's a little detail, but for the recent versions of Beam, you can use the `sdk_container_image` param instead of `worker_harness_container_image`.

Comment: Yeah, probably the Beam versions you are submitting the job from does not match the Beam version used by the container.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I installed the same beam version (`apache-beam[gcp]==2.40.0`) on the docker container I submitted the job from.

The above command works from the prebuilt worker harness image (`docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.40.0`).

My best guess is there's a mismatch in one of the other python dependencies in my custom docker image.  I got conflicts installing the older `dill` and `google-cloud-*` libraries recommended in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#python-3.9.12